# SQL query to get rows with a preference based on row value

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table that can have multiple records for `ip_address`. However, I want to return rows where `canceled=0` **if** multiple records of `ip_address` exist, otherwise get the first row where `canceled=1`

```
id  ip_address  username  canceled
0   10.10.10.1  john      0
1   10.10.10.1  johnny    1
2   10.10.10.1  quincy    1
3   10.10.10.2  bob       1
4   10.10.10.3  kristin   0
```

Examples returned resultset for `SELECT ip_address,username ....`:

```
10.10.10.1  john
10.10.10.2  bob
10.10.10.3  kristin
```

Using SQLAlchemy/Sqlite if that is of any relevance.

```
SELECT 
  b.id,
  a.ip_address,
  b.username,
  b.canceled
FROM (
  select distinct(ip_address) from mytable order by canceled) a,
  mytable b
WHERE
  b.ip_address=a.ip_address;
```

But that is returning multiple definitions for "ip_address"

Comment: How far have you gotten? Get started a query started and we can point out some specific issues.

Comment: SELECT b.id,a.ip_address,b.username,b.canceled FROM (select distinct(ip_address) from mytable order by canceled) a, mytable b WHERE b.ip_address=a.ip_address;

But that is returning multiple definitions for "ip_address"

Comment: _the first row where canceled=1_ by what measure? Ordered by `id`?

Comment: What database is this for?

Comment: Do you have a large amount of data? if so is there any index on the table?

Comment: It only has about 300 rows, so performance is not important, using SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper query appears to be:

`SELECT b.id,a.ip_address,b.username,b.canceled FROM (select distinct(ip_address) from mytable order by canceled) a, mytable b WHERE b.ip_address=a.ip_address GROUP BY b.ip_address`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming canceled is an int,this should work.

```
select *from #temp order by canceled
with cte as 
(
select ip_address,username,canceled,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by  ip_address order by canceled) as rn from #temp
)
select *from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: SQLite does not have window functions.

Comment: oops,i wrote htat for sql server.sorry i did not see the tag